# runnableFuture set result

Tags: java, concurrency, future

I want to do something like this:

**In thread1**:

```
Future<String> future = socketService.registerRequest(uuid);
System.out.println(future.get()); // I want to be blocked here while I will not signal from another thread
```

*registerRequest:*

```
public Future<String> registerRequest(String uuid) {
    RunnableFuture<String> runnableFuture = new FutureTask<String>(); // this code doesn't compile because it there is no default constructor 
    results.put(uuid, runnableFuture);
    return runnableFuture;
}
```

And in **another thread** I want to say smth like this

```
results.get(uuid).setResult("It is result from another thread")
```

How can I achieve it in java?

Comment: I nearly oversaw that you probably want to access a `Map` from both threads...  If so, you should mention that clearer from the beginning. If not, `ExecutorService.submit` is the easiest answer to block on `future.get()` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want is to be blocked in one thread until different thread puts some result in. I think BlockingQueue is good solution for you here is link with example [blocking queue example](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/blockingqueue.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, using an `ExecutorService`:

```
private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

public Future<String> registerRequest(String uuid) {
    RunnableFuture<String> runnableFuture = new FutureTask<String>(

    Future<String> future = executorService.submit(() -> {
         return "It is result from another thread";
    });

    // I left out the UUID part, please add yourself.

    return future;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to just call [`submit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit-java.util.concurrent.Callable-) on your [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and be fine, e.g.

```
ExecutorService yourExecutorService = /* e.g. */ Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
Future<String> future = yourExecutorService.submit(() -> "i am the answer created on another thread");

// the following line blocks, until the value is available:
System.out.println(future.get());
```

You may also want to look into [`Executors` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) and follow the documentation there.

Regarding [`FutureTask`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html): it is just a wrapper and offers two constructors, one [accepting a `Callable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html#FutureTask-java.util.concurrent.Callable-) and one a `Runnable`. But you may not even need this wrapping as shown before.